# How to use ListView in ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Idea here is to have a dynamic list consisting of dynamic lists.

Each of these inner dynamic lists is supposed to have different widgets, so I tried to create a ListView.

```
  List<String> list1 = ["pppp", "qqqq", "rrrr"];
  List<String> list2 = ["aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.separated(
                itemCount: list1.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {

                  return new ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: list2.length,

                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                        return new ListView(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        list2[Index],
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 25,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                      },
                  );
                },
              separatorBuilder: (context, build)=>Divider(
                thickness: 1,
                color: Color(0xff002540).withOpacity(.1),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now if I replace the ListView and place a normal Text there, the code works properly.
With ListView the contents are NOT shown.

Kindly guide.

Comment: Does adding `shrinkWrap: true` to your inner ListView solve it?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad Absolutely. Please post that as an answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does adding `shrinkWrap: true` to your inner ListView solve it?

```
    return new ListView.builder(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
       itemCount: list2.length,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
             return new ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true, //<= here
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                    list2[Index],
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 25,
             ),
            ),
           ],
          );
         },
        );
       },
```